# How do I get a gmail account on my HTC Cha Cha?

Tags: gmail, accounts, htc-chacha

I live in China and when I go to Settings > Accounts it's not an option to add a Gmail / Google one, is there any software I can download ?

Answer (score 1):

You can manually add a Gmail mailbox using IMAP in the separate Email app.

As to adding a Google account to sync your contacts and calendar, unfortunately a great many of Android devices obtained from China have this "issue". The best course of action is to flash a firmware meant for the same device, but from a different region.

THese links might help - [SuperDroidROM for ChaCha](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/download-android-2-3-3-gingerbread-superdroid-rom-for-htc-chacha/) // [HTC ChaCha forum on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1048)

Answer (score -1):

As to registering a new Google Account (Gmail Account), you can do it on this page: https://accounts.google.com/SignUp

As to how to add the Gmail account to your phone, you can do it from the Accounts & sync menu:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "Google" is not an account choice on Chinese firmware.